# What is the fastest and most accurate way to check if a website/URL exists.. Curl or PHP?

Tags: php, curl

What is the most accurate and fastest way to check if a URL exists? Example: Google.com.  I have been reading that I can use curl or I can use php file_exists() to locate the index file. I used this curl function...

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $ch = @curl_init($url);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $status = array();
    preg_match('/HTTP\/.* ([0-9]+) .*/', @curl_exec($ch) , $status);
    return ($status[1] == 200);
}
```

for example google.com but it returns false for google and true for other sites. I guess I am looking for the best solution to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for just a connection rather than a status code you can just use `fopen`...

```
if (!fopen($url, "r")) {
 // cannot connect
}
```

If you want to check the HTTP code then `curl` is probably the best way.

Comment: Isn't fopen slower in returning a result?

Comment: @Joe if you are really that concerned about speed, benchmark it yourself

Comment: @Gordon I didn't realize I could do that. Thanks

Comment: @Joe also, its somewhat revealing to ask for the fastest way and then place error suppression on almost every call as it slows down PHP as well.